# Table value returns nil when it should not be

Tags: lua, roblox, lua-table

My table:

```lua
local Cache = {
    SurvivalGameFramework = {
        parent = game.ServerStorage
    }
}
```

As you can probably tell, this table is not an empty value or "nil" but according to ROBLOX studio, `Cache[1]` is nil, and I've tried literally everything to figure out what is wrong with this engine.

`print(Cache[1])` will return nil and so will `Cache.SurvivalGameFramework[1]`.

Answer (score 0):

`Cache[1]` being `nil` is correct: The only key used in your `Cache` table is `SurvivalGameFramework`. `Cache.SurvivalGameFramework` in turn only has a `parent` key, so `Cache.SurvivalGameFramework[1]` is `nil` as well. `Cache.SurvivalGameFramework.parent` on the other hand would be `game.ServerStorage`.

A table `t = {42}` or `t = {[1] = 42}` would have `t[1] == 42`. A table `t2 = {k = 42}` or `t2 = {["k"] = 42}` has `t2.k == 42` and `t2["k"] == 42`. Absent keys have `nil` values in Lua, so `t2[1]` is `nil`.